# Необычный ввод строки

Tags: c++, c, строки, ввод, поток-ввода

Есть задача: вводится просто строка с цифрами и пробелами и задача вычленить из неё цифры для последующих с ними манипуляций(желательно в `int`). Например вводится:

```
for i:=99921 downto 20
```

И затем я получаю одной переменной просто:

```
9992120
```

Помогите реальзовать

Comment: В чем ваша проблема? Вы не знаете как пройти по всем символам строки? Как проверить символ на то, что он цифра? Или функции strcat и atol не понимаете?

Answer (score 1):

Проходим, выбрасываем все, что не есть цифра. Получаем нужную вам строку (без гарантии, что это влезет в `int`).

Что-то типа (в `s` - указатель на строку):

```
for(char* b = s, *e = s;*b; ++b)
{
    if (isdigit(*b) *e++ = *b;
}
*e = 0;
```

Можно со `string` - типа

```
string res;
for(auto c: s) if (isdigit(c)) res += c;
```

Не компилировал, но вроде идея понятна?

Ну, а уж строку цифр в число перевести, думаю, не проблема?